# Inserting Data in XML into Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

My task is to get data from One database (non oracle db) and insert that data into another database(oracle).

I am able to get the data from the source database in the form of XML. Now I have to pass this XML as input to the oracle database so that all the data inside the XML is inserted into the oracle database table.

Can some one please guide me as what is the code for doing the same. I am quite used to SQL Server 2005.

If some one can guide with how insert data in XMl into a table, it would be of great help.

Comment: I take it you want to parse the xml into columns?

Comment: Are you exporting and importing the data of a single table? Or is the data of several tables, possibly linked with references between the tables? Am I right that you don't want to store the data as XML but XML is just used as a means of data exchange? How big is such an XML file? Are we talking about mega, giga or tera bytes?

Comment: can you post a sample of the xml?

Answer (score 3):

This is as generic as I can make it without seeing the xml structure..

```
create or replace procedure put_stuff_into_table(source_xml_doc xmltype) AS

BEGIN

insert into table (a, b)
select *
from xmltable('<TOP_LEVEL_ELEMENT>'
              passing source_xml_doc
              columns a number        path 'ELEMENT_TAG_A',
                      b varchar2(100) path 'ELEMENT_TAG_B'
             );
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for replying . but my xml input will be a variable and not xml file . the xml format is stored in a variable and passed to stored procedure and now in stored procedure i need to use this xml variable and extract the data from it and insert into table.