# How to convert a list of items in SQL xml variable to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a very simple xml that I pass to a sql sproc as a parameter. But for simplicity I present it in declare.

```
declare @a xml;
set @a='<items>
  <item>1</item>
  <item>3</item>
  <item>5</item>
  <item>7</item>
</items>';
```

How do I convert this list to a table so I could make joins, etc. 
Basicly, How do I retrieve a table in the following form:

```
item
----
1
3
5
7
```

Thank you!

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263387/inserting-data-in-xml-into-oracle-database/6263943#6263943

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `nodes` function:

```
select  items.item.value('.','int')
from    @a.nodes('items/item') as items(item)
```